# Find all elements with href tag containing certain text with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

Lets say I have html code with three links

```
<a href="hey123"> Whatever </a>
<a href="hey321"> Whatever </a>
<a href="hi123"> Whatever </a>
```

and I want to use  selenium to find all elements which have a href tag which includes the string "hey" (in this case the first two links). How would I write python Selenium code which accomplishes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
all_href = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,  "//*[contains(@href, 'hey')]")
print(len(all_href)
```

Answer (score 1):

This XPath will do this work:

```
"//a[contains(@href,'hey')]"
```

To use that with Selenium you will need a `find_elements` or `findElements` method, depends on the language binding you use with Selenium.
For Selenium in Python this will give you the list of all such elements:

```
all_hey_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,  "//a[contains(@href, 'hey')]")
```